# Accessing Check box control that is in column header

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created an application aps.net c# within VS2019

I have a grid view, which has a checkbox in the column header.
Once a user has clicked on a seperate button to display, I would like to validate the checkbox called "chkALL" thats within the column header to see if it is checked or not. I cant seems to get the right syntax to do this.
Any advise please?

My ASPX code is here:
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Chg">

<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ChkAll_CheckedChanged" />



<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkRow" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ChkRow_CheckedChanged" RowIndex="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />

</asp:TemplateField>

This is the c# code I have tried

CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)tgvCorrelations.Column[13].FindControl("chkAll");

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function for use when firing the event change for the checked box

So this void it write:

```
 private void  ChkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        for (int i = 0; i < tgvCorrelations.Rows.Count; i++)  
            {  
                CheckBox chk = 
                 (CheckBox)tgvCorrelations.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");  
                if (chk.Checked)  
                {
    
                }
                else
                {
                    //...
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get/use and enjoy the value of the check box in the heading?

You can use find control against the GridView.HeaderRow.

So, assuming this markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdLoad" runat="server" Text="Load Data"
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdLoad_Click"
    />
<br />
<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" 
    Width="45%"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" 
                    OnCheckedChanged="chkSel_CheckedChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    Select All<br />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelAll" runat="server"
                    OnCheckedChanged="chkSelAll_CheckedChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"
                    />
                </div>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, when we hit the button to load the GridView, we then will get the value of the check box in the heading, and set all rows to checked (or un-checked).

So, the code to load our grid looks like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void cmdLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {

        CheckBox chkSelAll = new CheckBox();
        chkSelAll.Checked = false;
        bool HoldCheck = false;
        if (GVHotels.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            chkSelAll = (CheckBox)GVHotels.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkSelAll");
            HoldCheck = chkSelAll.Checked; 
        }

        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                          ORDER BY HotelName";

        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();

        chkSelAll = (CheckBox)GVHotels.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkSelAll");
        chkSelAll.Checked = HoldCheck;  

        CheckAll(chkSelAll.Checked);
    }

    protected void chkSel_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void chkSelAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkSelAll = (CheckBox)sender;
        CheckAll(chkSelAll.Checked);
    }

    void CheckAll(bool chk)
    {
        // check/un check all check box for each row

        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GVHotels.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkSel = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkSel");
            chkSel.Checked = chk;
        }
    }
```

Note VERY close, that WHEN we re-bind the GridView, then the setting of the check box is lost. So, if we are to re-bind the GridView, but ALSO respect the check box, then we get/grab/save the check box, re-load grid, and then re-set the check box back into the heading. (the value is LOST when we re-bind, so above code takes this into account).

Note that after the grid loads, one might still want to check all (or un-check all) by clicking on the header. That code is somewhat easier since we can use "sender" to get the check box in question.

So, that code is:

```
    protected void chkSelAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkSelAll = (CheckBox)sender;
        CheckAll(chkSelAll.Checked);
    }
```

However, the above code stub would and could use .FindControl of the GridView header object, but using sender is less code.

And the result is thus this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sorry only getting back to this now, Thank you for your response. I still need to access the checkbox in the header row but its to disable on enable it depending on a criteria. I have tried syntax you have suggested but I have done it on the rowDatabound as below:  CheckBox ctltest = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("ChkAll"); However, it retuns null System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
 error. I cant see any typo's in the aspx file. Which is as below:

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Action">
<HeaderTemplate> <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ChkAll_CheckedChanged" Visible="false" /> </HeaderTemplate><HeaderStyle Width="25px" /> <ItemTemplate> <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkRow" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ChkRow_CheckedChanged" RowIndex="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: I should also say I tried the below on loadGrid which also gave back null. CheckBox ctlChkAll = (CheckBox)tgvQuarantineStock.HeaderRow.FindControl("ChkAll");

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue, I was trying to access the header row before the  gridView was being populated. Moved the code to after the grid is populated and the attributes for the checkbox is there.